# How implement anchor using Drive API v3 from App Scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I would like to add comments into a gDoc as a simple example but including anchor feature. 
I followed the documentation [Manage comment and Discussions](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-comments) 
I can use **content** and **quotedFileContent** attributes but I can't represent a anchor.
the official definition:

> A region of the document represented as a JSON string. See anchor
>   documentation for details on how to define and interpret anchor
>   properties.
>   [Reference](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/comments/create)

The example proposed:

```
{
  'r': revisionId,
  'a': [
  {
    'line':
    {
      'n': 12,
      'l': 3,
    }
  },
  {
    'line':
    {
      'n': 18,
      'l': 1,
    }
  }]
}
```

[Reference](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-comments)

My idea is use App Scripts but I checked across "Try this API". (I included a fileID everything).The comment is impacted into the doc but the problem is the **anchor**. *I assume is a problem of the Json-format but I don't have working-elements to compare. Any idea?*

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure about  the **Json format** string  referenced, I trying to implement but always without good results. Do you have a working example using *txt* region classifiers? other classifiers is also valid for me.

Comment: To us the in-browser API tool you'll have to stringify your json object and pass it as a string. [Here's a guide to working with JSON files.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON)

Comment: I believe the issue is the **structure of the json** [related to anchor requirements]. Do you have a working example @DimuDesigns?

Comment: https://youtu.be/ZBU52nacbLw?t=312

Comment: I reviewed that video but it does not show a concrete example of the json-structure related *anchor* section. My objective is understand the anchor structure to create a comment. I can create general comments, also manipulate other properties but not the *anchor*. Finally the video demo I believe is created with a v2 of the API. @TheMaster

Comment: @Nicolas He specifically says that this is not possible. I've linked that time in my yt link above. Review with closed-captions, if English is not your native.

Comment: @TheMaster but is that material valid for v3? *I believe is different for the new version. If is still valid ok, but I believe is different. That is why I posted the question.